# Divide and compare two strings

Tags: java, string, split

I'm building an interpreter, and it's reading line by line. now let's suppose that A is a declared variable if the interpreter finds only letter a, it'll show its value, but if find "a" I want to show just a.

I don't know how to make the interpreter recognize "a". then eliminate " " and then evaluate only the letter a.

```
//the line below doesn't work
if(comands[i].equals("\"" + var[position].getNome() + "\"")){
    System.out.print(var[position].getName() + " ");
}
```

Comment: My question was Edited

Comment: It is still unclear what you want help with and what could be wrong with your code.

Comment: Do you mean to say that if your interpreter finds a letter you print it, and if it finds a letter within double quotes then also display the letter but without the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I can see, you want to be able to take a String, usually like `"A "` (without quotation marks) and remove the space.

1. Find the letter. An easy way to do this is `String.charAt(index)`. Basically, use a loop to find the letter. Create a `char` "value" variable (value will be a variable name for demonstration)
2. Check if it is a letter by using it's corresponding [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value (you could cast from `char` to `int`) and seeing if it is a letter or not. If it is a letter, do `value = String.charAt(i) // i is from the for loop`
3. `System.out.print(characterValue)`

Comment: Simply don't store the space in the char variable you print?

Answer (score 0):

You can first identify all the strings that are in double-quotes and make it a list and then match it with your declared variable.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringContains {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String fileData = "Welcome! to A \"A\" \"What A DAY\"";
        String declaredVariable = "A";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(fileData);
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (m.find()) {
            stringList.add(m.group(1));
        }

        for(String s : stringList) {
            if(s.matches(declaredVariable)) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```